# The music app noise doesn't open

Tags: release-juno, music

```
bonifacio@bonifacio-PC:~$ noise
Command 'noise' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install openfoam
bonifacio@bonifacio-PC:~$ sudo apt install openfoam
[sudo] пароль для bonifacio:                  
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Следующие пакеты устанавливались автоматически и больше не требуются:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-52 linux-headers-4.15.0-52-generic linux-image-4.15.0-52-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-52-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-52-generic
Для их удаления используйте «sudo apt autoremove».
Следующие НОВЫЕ пакеты будут установлены:
  openfoam
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 1 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 0 пакетов не обновлено.
Установлено или удалено не до конца 14 пакетов.
Необходимо скачать 0 B/17,2 MB архивов.
После данной операции объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 118 MB.
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 274663 файла и каталога.)
Подготовка к распаковке …/openfoam_4.1+dfsg1-2_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается openfoam (4.1+dfsg1-2) …
dpkg: ошибка при обработке архива /var/cache/apt/archives/openfoam_4.1+dfsg1-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 попытка перезаписать «/usr/share/man/man1/noise.1.gz», который уже имеется в пакете noise 5.0.4+r2721+pkg114~ubuntu5.0.1
dpkg-deb: ошибка: вставка subprocess was killed by signal (Обрыв канала)
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openfoam_4.1+dfsg1-2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` indicates a package installer error. This can happen after a failed software installation, or if the installer becomes corrupted.

Looks like some packages have been unpacked but not installed (probably due to a connection failure). You can try to fix your dpkg database by running this command:

```
sudo dpkg ––configure –a
```

and then trying to re-install the desired software.

Comment: `sudo dpkg ––configure –a` fixed a lot of simmilar issues for me